# Keep getting net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT when POSTing to Node.js application on Ubuntu 18.04 hosted by Digital Ocean

Tags: node.js, http, ubuntu, nginx, https

I am trying to run a Node.js (LTS 12 - MEAN stack) application I am working on on a Ubuntu 18.04 server hosted by Digital Ocean. I started out by following one of their [guides](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-18-04) for setting up such an app. The guide makes you use Nginx (with SSL using Let’s Encrypt certificates) and sets up Nginx as a Reverse Proxy Server. I got it to work so far (meaning that when I go to [domain name].nl/login I see my login page and all the assets get loaded and stuff), but whenever I try to login in I get the following message:

> POST https://[domain name].nl:3000/user/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

I have been trying to fix this for literal hours, but I can't figure out why this keeps happening since it doesn't happen when I run the app locally. Domain name and IP address have been redacted.

Relevant part of *index.js* file:

```
const http = require('http');
const app = express();

// Initialize middleware
app.use(helmet());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(cors());
app.use(passport.initialize());

// Define routing
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.use('/user', require('./server/routes/user-route'));
app.use('/shop', require('./server/routes/shop-route'));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'))
});


// Start listening on port 3000 for requests.
const server = http.createServer(app).listen(3000, () => console.log(`Server listen: http://[ip address]:3000`));
```

*etc/nginx/sites-enabled/[domain name].nl* AND *etc/nginx/sites-available/[domain name].nl* files:

```
server {

        root /var/www/[domain name].nl/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name [domain name].nl.com www.[domain name].nl;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/[domain name].nl/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/[domain name].nl/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = www.[domain name].nl) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name [domain name].nl.com www.[domain name].nl;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

*sudo ufw status verbose* output:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp (OpenSSH)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full)    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp (OpenSSH (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Executing POST request:

```
this.http.post(`${environment.ENDPOINT}/user/login`, user);
```

Where *environment.ENDPOINT* is equal to:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  ENDPOINT: 'https://[domain name].nl:3000'
};
```

I have tried adding port 3000 to the firewall, changing the nginx *proxy_pass* to the IP address or domain name of the server and interchanging http and https in a number of places, but I still couldn't get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just also tried changing the _ENDPOINT_ variable to 'http://[domain name].nl:3000' instead of _https_, but that resulted in the followin error: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://[domain name]/login' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://[domain name]:3000/user/login'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.